Flutter native splash screen keep showing default splash
I have added the flutter_native_splash package inside my dependancies and have added this native_splash code in my pubspec.yaml file
flutter_native_splash: ^2.4.0

flutter_native_splash:
  color: "#FFFFFF"
  image: assets/images/Logo.png

  android_12:
    color: "#FFFFFF"
    image: assets/images/Logo.png
  android: true
  ios: true
  web: false

and the results when creating is also showing no errors
Building package executable... (6.0s)
Built flutter_native_splash:create.
[Android] Creating default splash images
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Deleting android12splash.png
[Android] Updating launch background(s) with splash image path...
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable/launch_background.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable-night/launch_background.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable-v21/launch_background.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/drawable-night-v21/launch_background.xml
[Android] Updating styles...
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values-v31/styles.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values-night-v31/styles.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml
[Android]  - android/app/src/main/res/values-night/styles.xml
[iOS] Creating  images
[iOS] Updating ios/Runner/Info.plist for status bar hidden/visible

✅ Native splash complete.
Now go finish building something awesome!  You rock! 
Like the package? Please give it a  here: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_splash

despite showing no errors, my native splash screen is still the default flutter splash as seen below


is it androit? or both?

right now I'm testing on android only but planning to have it run on IOS

To resolve the default splash screen issue in Android 12, you can replace it with a transparent screen by modifying your styles.xml file. Here are the steps:
Go to android\app\src\main\res\values\styles.xml and edit the file as follows:
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> <!-- add this line -->
    </style>

</resources>

Adding the line <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item> will make the splash screen transparent, resolving the issue with the default splash screen in Android 12.

I added the line as you suggested, stop the run completely and re run the app again but still got the same result

what do you mean re run. All you have to do is save the changes and rebuild the app

I did re build, but still got the same result

i have the same problem, and translucent not work. if set to true, the splash disappear. the windowSplashScreenBackground appear to be a mask of opacity. if set #FFFFFF the background goes 100% opacity. if set like #999999, appear like 60% opacity, if set #000000 appear all black, no opacity. Look https://imgur.com/a/J0K2hcN, the first one, is a light green, but appear dark green. Android 13, Xiaomi Dark mode here

as from my expirience, this problem is related to the android only. so, you could add this line:
<item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>

to your styles.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window while the process is starting when the OS's Dark Mode setting is off -->
    <style name="LaunchTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <!-- Show a splash screen on the activity. Automatically removed when
             the Flutter engine draws its first frame -->
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@drawable/launch_background</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
    <!-- Theme applied to the Android Window as soon as the process has started.
         This theme determines the color of the Android Window while your
         Flutter UI initializes, as well as behind your Flutter UI while its
         running.

         This Theme is only used starting with V2 of Flutter's Android embedding. -->
    <style name="NormalTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowBackground">?android:colorBackground</item>
        <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    </style>
</resources>

if neede you should do it in values-night/styles.xml also. more info here

Hi, I did exactly what you suggested but it still didn't work for me
